# pentaho cde include/exclude where clause in sql query

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am building a Dashboard using Pentaho CDE, in which a table will show data from a query like this :

```
select * from types where id = ${id}
```

Now i get the id from url parameter like this

```
id = Dashboards.getQueryParameter('id');
```

If I dont give the id in url, the table shows nothing as id='' doesn't match anything. But what I want to do is, if I dont give id it will exclude the where clause and show a result of query like

```
select * from types
```

How to achieve this in pentaho CDE ?

Comment: you can hadle this using a store procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two datasources and choose one during the `Pre Execution` phase of a table. The **datasource** of a dashboard's component (table, chart) is represented by a property `dataAccessId`.

You can set the `dataAccessId` using JavaScript code inside a component like this: `this.chartDefinition.dataAccessId = {datasource name}`.

1) Datasource `sql_with_id`:

```
select * from types where id = ${id}
```

2) Datasource = `sql_no_id`:

```
select * from types
```

Table's `Pre Execution` code:

```
function f() {
   var id = Dashboards.getQueryParameter('id');
   if (id && id !== "") {
      this.chartDefinition.dataAccessId = "sql_with_id";
   } else {
      this.chartDefinition.dataAccessId = "sql_no_id";
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not using charts, just table, do you know how I can change table data source dynamically ?

Comment: The `Table Component` has also `Pre Execution` phase as well as all CDE components do. It can be found in component's `Advanced Properties` tab.

Comment: I know that but I didn't find any dataAccessId

Comment: `dataAccessId` is a table's property which represents CDE's `Datasource`

Comment: If you use a FireBug plugin use can check dashboard's DOM and search a name of property which represent the `Datasource`: `FireBug > DOM > Dashboards > components > component["Object type=Table"] > chartDefinition > dataAccessId`

Comment: yes in fact it has. Although i resorted to kettle queries, but it is a valid answer. post it as answer and I will be happy to accept.

Comment: I have extended my answer.

Comment: Do you know how to achieve the same for pentaho report designer ? @mzy

Comment: No, I have never worked with Pentaho Report Designer.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a custom javascript parameter (say, 'where_clause') a bit like this:

```
id = Dashboards.getQueryParameter('id');
if (id != null)
    where_clause = 'id = ' + id;
else
    where_clause = '1=1';
 return where_clause;
```

And then build your query:

```
select * from types where ${where_clause}
```

Comment: umm it doesn't work like that, it shows wrong query.